# Is it possible to maintain an EventSource connection after a page refresh?

Tags: javascript, c#, server-sent-events

I'm trying to implement a Javascript EventSource connection to my C# backend to get status updates from the backend for a lengthy task. I'm using this https://github.com/EventSource/eventsource wrapper so I can send authentication headers to the backend. My frontend implementation is as follows:

`<button onClick={() => openEventSource('/endpoint')}>Run Task</button>`

```
function openEventSource(endpoint) {
  const source = new EventSource(endpoint, { headers: { Authorization: token } });
  const onError = () => {
    // Handle Error
    source.close();
  };

  source.onerror = onError;

  source.addEventListener('complete', (e) => {
    const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
    // update UI to show task is completed
    source.close();
  });
}
```

My C# backend code is based on this article: https://itnext.io/server-side-event-streams-with-dotnet-core-and-typescript-d20c84017480 with the contents of the "/endpoint" controller looking similar to the following:

```
await HttpContext.SSEInitAsync();
// Run Task
await HttpContext.SSESendEventAsync(
    new SSEEvent("complete", new { Foo = "foo" })
    {
        Id = "event id",
        Retry = 10
    }
);
```

This code works well as long as I remain on the same webpage and wait for the task to complete. The task can take an extremely long time to complete, so I thought it would be a better user experience if they could access other parts of the site while waiting. However, once the user refreshes or navigates to a different page the frontend no longer shows any signs of attempting to maintain this connection with the backend, so it does not update properly once the task completes. I've heard conflicting reports on whether or not it's possible to persist EventSource connections across pages like this so I figured I'd ask if it is and if so, how can I do it? Or are there alternatives that will do the trick? Thanks.